# Is it possible to have auto complete capability in R terminal in VSCode not just in .R file

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

The radian extension is great in that it allows for syntax highlighting and auto-completion inside a .R file that is loaded into VSCode. This is great when one is working on a project. However, when one is just learning something new using R (say, learning a new package by typing many lines that are useful only for the moment and no point in saving the lines), one has to take the trouble to load a .R file solely for the purpose of enjoying the convenience brought about by radian and delete the .R file after finished learning.

I think this is a condition where directly typing in the terminal is more convenient. However, while the terminal in RStudio allows for auto-completion, this is not the case in VSCode. Is there a way to enable code auto-completion in R terminal inside VSCode? Or is everyone enjoying working on .R file even when just typing lines that will not be saved?

Comment: Are you using this radian terminal? It should provide autocompletion. https://github.com/randy3k/radian